# Php mysql search result display listing in column ID

Tags: php, mysql

I got below php script doing search for mysql database which is working fine, i try to list the search result in a table and first column "ID", eg. if search result found 10 records, the table will list 10 records from No.1,2,3.....10 in column ID; been googling for solution for whole day and unable to get it right, anyone can enlighten me how to achieve this? Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   

  <body>

    <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
    <form method="post" action="welcome">
      <h2>WELCOME</h2>
      <p>Search criteria: key in name</p>
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
<br/>
<div align="left"><Font size="4"><a href="logout.php" style="margin-right:80px;">LOGOUT</a></font></div><br>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
    
    require "2-search.php";
    
    echo ' <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"> 
      <tr> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">No</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Prepaid</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">postpaid</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Fiber</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Flex Device</font> </td> 
          
          <td> <font face="Arial">Name</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">class</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">AM</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">AT</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">shopfront_signage</font> </td> 
          
          <td> <font face="Arial">Photo1</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Photo2</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Photo3</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Photo4</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Photo5</font> </td> 
          
      </tr>';

    // DISPLAY RESULTS
    if (count($results) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($results as $r)
        {

            $field1name = $results; //<-----------this is first column ID to list the result from 1,2,3....
            $field2name = $r["pre_code"];
            $field3name = $r["post_code"];
            $field4name = $r["f_code"];
            $field5name = $r["device"];
            $field6name = $r["Name"];
            $field7name = $r["class"];
            $field8name = $r["AM"];
            $field9name = $r["AT"];
            $field10name = $r["shopfront_signage"];
            $field11name = $r["p1"];
            $field12name = $r["p2"];
            $field13name = $r["p3"];
            $field14name = $r["p4"];
            $field15name = $r["p5"];

            if ($field11name == '')
            {
                $img = 'default.png';
            }
            else
            {
                $img = $field11name;
            }
            if ($field12name == '')
            {
                $img2 = 'default.png';
            }
            else
            {
                $img2 = $field12name;
            }
            if ($field13name == '')
            {
                $img3 = 'default.png';
            }
            else
            {
                $img3 = $field13name;
            }
            if ($field14name == '')
            {
                $img4 = 'default.png';
            }
            else
            {
                $img4 = $field14name;
            }
            if ($field15name == '')
            {
                $img5 = 'default.png';
            }
            else
            {
                $img5 = $field15name;
            }

         
            echo '<tr style="width: 259px; vertical-align:top"> 
                  <td>' . $field1name . '</td>
                  <td>' . $field2name . '</td> 
                  <td >' . $field3name . '</td> 
                  <td >' . $field4name . '</td> 
                     <td>' . $field5name . '</td> 
                  <td>' . $field6name . '</td> 
                  <td >' . $field7name . '</td> 
                  <td >' . $field8name . '</td> 
                     <td>' . $field9name . '</td> 
                  <td>' . $field10name . '</td> 
                                 
                  <td><a href="/dealer/search/images/' . $img . '" target = "_blank"><img src="/dealer/search/images/' . $img . '" height="100" width="120"></td>
 <td><a href="/dealer/search/images/' . $img2 . '" target = "_blank"><img src="/dealer/search/images/' . $img2 . '" height="100" width="120"></td>
 <td><a href="/dealer/search/images/' . $img3 . '" target = "_blank"><img src="/dealer/search/images/' . $img3 . '" height="100" width="120"></td>
 <td><a href="/dealer/search/images/' . $img4 . '" target = "_blank"><img src="/dealer/search/images/' . $img4 . '" height="100" width="120"></td>
 <td><a href="/dealer/search/images/' . $img5 . '" target = "_blank"><img src="/dealer/search/images/' . $img5 . '" height="100" width="120"></td>

                   </tr>';
            
        }
        $result->free();

    }
    else
    {
        echo '<FONT COLOR="RED" SIZE="5">   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; >> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; NO RESULTS FOUND  </FONT>';
    }
    
    
}

?>
  </body>
 
  
</html>
```

Comment: what is the name of the ID column in your database table? I assume you just want to use that? if so then e.g. `$r["id"]` would be what you need. Or are you trying to create a _count_ of the records? e.g. 1st record, 2nd record, 3rd record, regardless of its unique ID? It wasn't totally clear from your wording.

Comment: what is <form `action="welcome"`>???

Comment: there is `attribute` required <input type="submit" `name="search"`>

Comment: Kumar, i used htaccess to hide php extension, 'welcome' & 'search' no problem.

Comment: ADyson, i don't want to use mysql database for ID filed (because ID will return number not in sequence, eg. 12, 25,54,66...due to search result), instead to list the number based on search result count and put them in sequence from 1,2,3....hope this clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a quick look at the code it seems you may have simply forgotten to close the table tag.

try putting this at the end of your if statement.

```
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got my code working, here is the solution:

1. add this in php : $i=0;
2. add this in table row: ++$i

Thanks.